# Make all the text box to non - editable upon a button click

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Swing coding.I have 3 text box and one button.
Upon clicking of the button I want to disable/deactivate the three text boxes.
I added the below code in the button actionPerformed function.It doesn't disable/make it non editable.

```
myTextField.setEditable(false);
myTextField.setEnabled(false);
mytask() //it taskes almost 30 minutes
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We can't tell what you code is doing based on 3 lines of code.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mytask() //it taskes almost 30 minutes

Your long running task to should execute on a separate Thread. If you invoke the long running task in the ActionListener then the GUI will freeze until the task finishes executing.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You will probably want to use a `SwingWorker` for the task.

> I added the below code in the button actionPerformed function.It doesn't disable/make it non editable

If you already invoke the task in a separate Thread, then it means you don't have a reference to the text field that you add the frame. Maybe you created two instances.

Comment: I could achieve what I wanted by using Swing Worker.